# Is this XSLT code absurd or not?

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to modify a xsl sheet written by someone else. but for now I'm just trying to understand...
I'm really surprised to read this :

```
<xsl:template match="par">

    [...]

    <xsl:variable name="pos"><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="page"><xsl:value-of select="../par[position()=$pos]/@page"/></xsl:variable>

    [...]

    <xsl:if test="$page!=''">
    <xsl:if test="$page!=@page">
        <div style="text-align:right;page-break-before:always">
        <font color="#000000" style="font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;font-weight:normal">
                - <xsl:value-of select="$page"/> -
            <br/>
         </font>
        </div>
    </xsl:if>
    </xsl:if>

    [...]

</xsl:template>
```

am I stupid or is this code stupid?

And if it's me, can someone explain me ***How in this case could $page and @page be different?***

thanks

Comment: That might be a good question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: That's impossible to answer with the `[...]` in place.

`@page` is the `page` attribute of the *current* node.
`$page` is the `page` attribute of the `$pos`-th `par` node.

Why do you think they should be equal?

Comment: @hroptatyr and the $pos is the the current position ?

Comment: I don't know what happens in the `[...]` bit.  You could change the current node.  Up there `$pos` is the position of the current node, yes.  But that node need not be a `par` node.

Comment: @hroptatyr ok I start to understand what you meen. but as we are in a 'xsl:template match="par">' the current node in not necessary a 'par' ?

Comment: not necessarily, no.  A `<xsl:for-each ...>` for instance changes the current node.

Comment: @hroptatyr ok there is no `<xsl:for-each ...>` in all code in [...] there is noting else than if, choose, ... and there is no call to the par template. thanks for your answer. I think I'm going to comment the code and do many tests more and see. for now tests i've done don't show any difference with or without the code.

Comment: @Sebange: I think these things happen when you copy (fragments of) code from here to there.  Maybe it was in a named template or a for-each loop before.

Comment: @Sebange: The code cannot be "stupid" -- only its author can be ... :) The code is ugly and I personally will never accept or use such code. Whether or not the attribute and the variable have always the same string value is almost impossible to say -- especially with the elipsis all around. It certainly is possible to show an example, where these values are different, but we don;t know the complete specific code in your case.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about XSL coding styles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, the string values of `$page` and `@page` can be different:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[@page mod 2 = 0]"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="par">      
        <xsl:variable name="pos">
            <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:variable name="page">
            <xsl:value-of select="../par[position()=$pos]/@page"/>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:if test="$page!=''">
            <xsl:if test="$page!=@page">
                <div style="text-align:right;page-break-before:always">
                    <font color="#000000" style="font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;font-weight:normal">                 - 
                        <xsl:value-of select="$page"/> -             
                        <br/>
                    </font>
                </div>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:if>  
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<t>
 <par page="1"/>
 <par page="2"/>
 <par page="3"/>
 <par page="4"/>
 <par page="5"/>
 <par page="6"/>
 <par page="7"/>
</t>
```

**The produced result is all due to the inequality of `$page` and `@page` in the above code**:

```
<div style="text-align:right;page-break-before:always">
   <font color="#000000" style="font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;font-weight:normal">                 - 
                        1 -             
                        <br/>
   </font>
</div>
<div style="text-align:right;page-break-before:always">
   <font color="#000000" style="font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;font-weight:normal">                 - 
                        2 -             
                        <br/>
   </font>
</div>
<div style="text-align:right;page-break-before:always">
   <font color="#000000" style="font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;font-weight:normal">                 - 
                        3 -             
                        <br/>
   </font>
</div>
```

**Explanation**:

Within a template or in an `xsl:for-each`, the expression:

```
position()
```

is the position of the *current node* in the *current node-list*. This is generally not the same as the position of the current node within the node-set of its identically-named siblings.

Comment: +1 for explaining the ways in which `position()` changes its function based on where it is used.

Answer (score 1):

The "standalone" `position()` function used to set `$pos` is very context dependent and is calculated differently from a `position()` within square brackets when you set `$page` variable.

Consider an example (tested here http://xslttest.appspot.com/ ):

Source XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>CBS Records</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1988</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Greatest Hits</title>
        <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>RCA</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1982</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Still got the blues</title>
        <artist>Gary Moore</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>Virgin records</company>
        <price>10.20</price>
        <year>1990</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Eros</title>
        <artist>Eros Ramazzotti</artist>
        <country>EU</country>
        <company>BMG</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1997</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>One night only</title>
        <artist>Bee Gees</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>Polydor</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1998</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Sylvias Mother</title>
        <artist>Dr.Hook</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>CBS</company>
        <price>8.10</price>
        <year>1973</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Maggie May</title>
        <artist>Rod Stewart</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>Pickwick</company>
        <price>8.50</price>
        <year>1990</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Romanza</title>
        <artist>Andrea Bocelli</artist>
        <country>EU</country>
        <company>Polydor</company>
        <price>10.80</price>
        <year>1996</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>When a man loves a woman</title>
        <artist>Percy Sledge</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Atlantic</company>
        <price>8.70</price>
        <year>1987</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Black angel</title>
        <artist>Savage Rose</artist>
        <country>EU</country>
        <company>Mega</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1995</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>1999 Grammy Nominees</title>
        <artist>Many</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Grammy</company>
        <price>10.20</price>
        <year>1999</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>For the good times</title>
        <artist>Kenny Rogers</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>Mucik Master</company>
        <price>8.70</price>
        <year>1995</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Big Willie style</title>
        <artist>Will Smith</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1997</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Tupelo Honey</title>
        <artist>Van Morrison</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>Polydor</company>
        <price>8.20</price>
        <year>1971</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Soulsville</title>
        <artist>Jorn Hoel</artist>
        <country>Norway</country>
        <company>WEA</company>
        <price>7.90</price>
        <year>1996</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>The very best of</title>
        <artist>Cat Stevens</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>Island</company>
        <price>8.90</price>
        <year>1990</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Stop</title>
        <artist>Sam Brown</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>A and M</company>
        <price>8.90</price>
        <year>1988</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Bridge of Spies</title>
        <artist>T`Pau</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>Siren</company>
        <price>7.90</price>
        <year>1987</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Private Dancer</title>
        <artist>Tina Turner</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>Capitol</company>
        <price>8.90</price>
        <year>1983</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Midt om natten</title>
        <artist>Kim Larsen</artist>
        <country>EU</country>
        <company>Medley</company>
        <price>7.80</price>
        <year>1983</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Pavarotti Gala Concert</title>
        <artist>Luciano Pavarotti</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>DECCA</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1991</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>The dock of the bay</title>
        <artist>Otis Redding</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Atlantic</company>
        <price>7.90</price>
        <year>1987</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Picture book</title>
        <artist>Simply Red</artist>
        <country>EU</country>
        <company>Elektra</company>
        <price>7.20</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Red</title>
        <artist>The Communards</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>London</company>
        <price>7.80</price>
        <year>1987</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Unchain my heart</title>
        <artist>Joe Cocker</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>EMI</company>
        <price>8.20</price>
        <year>1987</year>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

Test XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="cd">
     [<xsl:value-of select="position()"/>]<xsl:value-of select="title"/>
    <xsl:variable name="pos"><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></xsl:variable>
     [- <xsl:value-of select="$pos"/>]
     [+ <xsl:value-of select="../cd[position()=$pos]/position()"/>]<xsl:value-of select="../cd[position()=$pos]/title"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
     [2]Empire Burlesque
     [- 2]
     [+ 1]Hide your heart

     [4]Hide your heart
     [- 4]
     [+ 1]Still got the blues

     [6]Greatest Hits
     [- 6]
     [+ 1]One night only

     [8]Still got the blues
     [- 8]
     [+ 1]Maggie May

     [10]Eros
     [- 10]
     [+ 1]When a man loves a woman

     [12]One night only
     [- 12]
     [+ 1]1999 Grammy Nominees

     [14]Sylvias Mother
     [- 14]
     [+ 1]Big Willie style

     [16]Maggie May
     [- 16]
     [+ 1]Soulsville

     [18]Romanza
     [- 18]
     [+ 1]Stop

     [20]When a man loves a woman
     [- 20]
     [+ 1]Private Dancer

     [22]Black angel
     [- 22]
     [+ 1]Pavarotti Gala Concert

     [24]1999 Grammy Nominees
     [- 24]
     [+ 1]Picture book

     [26]For the good times
     [- 26]
     [+ 1]Unchain my heart

     [28]Big Willie style
     [- 28]
     [+ ]

     [30]Tupelo Honey
     [- 30]
     [+ ]

     [32]Soulsville
     [- 32]
     [+ ]

     [34]The very best of
     [- 34]
     [+ ]

     [36]Stop
     [- 36]
     [+ ]

     [38]Bridge of Spies
     [- 38]
     [+ ]

     [40]Private Dancer
     [- 40]
     [+ ]

     [42]Midt om natten
     [- 42]
     [+ ]

     [44]Pavarotti Gala Concert
     [- 44]
     [+ ]

     [46]The dock of the bay
     [- 46]
     [+ ]

     [48]Picture book
     [- 48]
     [+ ]

     [50]Red
     [- 50]
     [+ ]

     [52]Unchain my heart
     [- 52]
     [+ ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your sample I understand now what u meen by "context dependent". but in your sample the [x] is always equal to [- x]

Comment: Correct. I just check if the variable is set correctly. This output is not really needed. Important is that `position()` does depend on how and where it is called from. In "standalone" version it counts all XML elements (in my example), and in square brackets `../cd[position()=$pos]` it counts only `cd` elements.